# Create temporary table in OutSystems when internal database is Oracle?

Tags: outsystems

Is it possible to create a temporary table using an Advanced SQL widget in OutSystems when your internal database is Oracle.

I know how to create a temporary entity using an Advanced SQL widget when the internal database is SQL Server and all of the example seem to assume that.

I know how to create a temporary table in Oracle.  The question is how to do that in an Advanced SQL widget in OutSystems.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not experienced with oracle, but can you just add the SQL query in the advanced query in Outsystems? As long you got the needed permissions it should work right? What are the problems that you encountered?

Answer (score 0):

Permissions would be the biggest challenge here, you would need OutSystems to be connected to Oracle using a user with DDL access to CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE. That, and it is not recommended, but **yes** it is possible.

According to the documentation (https://success.outsystems.com/documentation/11/developing_an_application/use_data/query_data/sql_queries/#avoid-data-definition-language),

> Avoid Data Definition Language
> The SQL tool should only be used to execute the following: SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements. Using Data Definition Language (DDL) statements like CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE, DROP TABLE, etc. might make the OutSystems metamodel inconsistent, leading to misbehavior.